# dumping geopandas to HDFStore

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, hdfstore

I parse csv into pandas and then into geopandas [from here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html)
I create the `stations` DataFrame, with a following:

```
stations_pd['pos'] = [Point(loc[0], loc[1]) for loc in locs]
```

then I create geopandas from this:

```
stations_gpd = gpd.GeoDataFrame(stations_pd)
```

and want to dump it to HDFStore:

```
store = pd.HDFStore("test.h5")
store['pd'] = stations_pd
```

this is fine, yet the same with geopnadas raises error:

```
store['gpd'] = stations_gpd
```

error is:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 486, in __setitem__
    self.put(key, value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 866, in put
    self._write_to_group(key, value, append=append, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1323, in _write_to_group
    encoding=encoding, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1237, in _create_storer
    error('_TYPE_MAP')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/pytables.py", line 1213, in error
    % (t, group, type(value), format, append, kwargs)
TypeError: cannot properly create the storer for: [_TYPE_MAP] [group->/stations (Group) '',value-><class 'geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame'>,format->fixed,append->False,kwargs->{'encoding': None}]
```

Comment: Indeed type is checked and valid types are listed [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/509e03c6b113e78935ae46707572e4bf7f7a1df5/pandas/io/pytables.py#L176). I guess the best way is convert back your geodataframe to pandas dataframe and vice versa when using the store.

Comment: Writing a GeoDataFrame to hdf5 is not supported, also not in geopandas (and also not easy to support). Best is probably indeed to convert the geometry column to something else (bytes or string) that you can later convert again on read). But there are also many other formats that you can use to store the GeoDataFrame.